# How to calculate $\lim_{t\to 0^+} \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\exp\frac{x+1-e^x}{t}dx$

Tags: analysis

How to calculate $$\lim_{t\to 0^+} \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\exp\frac{x+1-e^x}{t}dx$$

I have known that it has connection with $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2}dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$$
and I try to let $u=\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}$ but then I can't find a way to continue...

Comment: Substitute $x=y\sqrt{t}$ (in the *original* integral) and apply [DCT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@metamorphy's tip obtains$$\lim_{t\to0^+}\int_0^\infty\exp\tfrac{1+y\sqrt{t}-e^{y\sqrt{t}}}{t}dy=\int_0^\infty\exp\lim_{t\to0^+}\tfrac{1+y\sqrt{t}-e^{y\sqrt{t}}}{t}dy=\int_0^\infty\exp(-\tfrac12y^2)dy=\sqrt{\tfrac{\pi}{2}}.$$